# Properly merge array values

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

We have the following `mymodule_preprocess_node` hook where we add two arrays with two `key-value pairs`. In `twig`, we would like to merge the values.

How would we merge the two arrays in `twig`?

Here is what we tried.

**mymodule_preprocess_node**

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // perform some logic.

  $variables['content']['ary']['foo'] = 'foo_value';
  $variables['content']['ary']['bar'] = 'bar_value';
}
```

**node--article.html.twig**

```
{% set twigAry = [] %}
{% for key, value in content.ary %}
  {$ set twigAry = twigAry|merge({ key : value }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

This results in `twigAry` only having the following. It basically prints the last `key` and `value`, which is `bar` and `bar_value`. Strangely enough, instead of setting the key to `bar` it results in the key being `key`.

```
[
  'key' => 'bar_value'
]
```

**Desired Output**

```
[ 
  'foo' => 'foo_value`, 
  'bar' => 'bar_value',
]
```

In the twig template, we are adding an inline `<script>` tag that needs to have the array in the desired output as such we need to have in this format in twig. For example, when we load the [Marketo form](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/forms/examples/), we want to set some values like this. Rather than hardcoding items in twig, we will just use the `['foo']` and `['bar']` from the preprocess method.

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function(form) {
    // Set the value of the Phone and Country fields
    form.vals({ "Phone":"555-555-1234", "Country":"USA"});
});
```

**Final twig:**

```
{% set twigAry = [] %}
{% for key, value in content.ary %}
  {$ set twigAry = twigAry|merge({ key : value }) %}
{% endfor %}

MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function(form) {
  // Set the value of the Phone and Country fields
  form.vals({ twigAry });
});
```

Comment: You already have the preprocess going, why make twig do it?

Comment: @Kevin I have updated the question with a description on this. In general, we have an inline `<script>` that requires the ` { 'key' : value }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash `{ key: value }` is equivalent to `{ 'key': value }`.

Solution:

```
{# key as expression (the expression must be enclosed into parentheses) #}

{ (key): value }
```

See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#literals

Comment: that link was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Associative arrays must use curly brackets in Twig:

`{% set twigAry = {} %}`

Arrays with square brackets `[]` defined in Twig don't have key names